# Best practice to recode multiple subsets

Tags: r, data.table

I'm curious if there's a better way to recode data.tables based on subset logic.  In the contrived example below, I want to avoid dividing by 0:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(V1 = rep(1, 100),
                 V2 = sample(x = c(0,1,2), size = 100, replace = TRUE))

dt[V2 > 0, V3 := V1/V2]
dt[V2 == 0, V3 := 0]
```

Comment: the answer below gives you more options, but I think you need to define what "better" means here..?

Comment: use `set.seed()` when using `sample()` so we can have the same example code as you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a column of zeros first, then do the first subset calculation.

```
dt[, V3 := 0][V2 > 0, V3 := V1/V2]
```

Or you could use `ifelse()` and do it all at once.

```
dt[, V3 := ifelse(V2 > 0, V1/V2, 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact you don't want to divide. What you want is to divide with exception, so what you can do is to define own divide function, see `%/2%` below.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(
    V1 = rep(1, 100),
    V2 = sample(x = c(0,1,2), size = 100, replace = TRUE)
)
# replace Inf after dividing
dt = copy(DT)
dt[, V3 := V1/V2
   ][!is.finite(V3), V3 := 0
     ][]
# use own divide function
`%/2%` <- function(e1, e2) ifelse(e2==0, 0, `/`(e1, e2))
dt = copy(DT)
dt[, V3 := V1 %/2% V2
   ][]
```